# SAMD21E with Arduino : SPI

Tags: arduino, spi, serial, memory, samd21

I created a custom board with a SAMD21E chip ([thanks to this](http://www.technoblogy.com/show?2833)).
I2C protocol works very well.

Nevertheless, the SPI line from the Arduino Zero use PB pins which are not present on SAMD21E chip, so I need to create a custom SPI line. I followed Adafruit tutorial to do that but I don't know how to connect my custom SPI with SerialFlash library (or the Spark Fun Serial Flash Library).

My goal is to connect the Serial Flash Breakout - SPX-17115.

Comment: What is the question you want answered?

Comment: Use my custom SPI with SerialFlash library which use the SPI library

Answer (score 0):

The SerialFlash library may be hardcoded to use the standard SPI class and pins, in which case you will need to modify it (the library) so that it uses your custom SPI.

Comment: Thanks. Can you help me to do that ? How can I change the pins in the library ? Don’t know how to do it